# How to change data type of a graph operation in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a decoder which requires Conv2DTranspose , but tensorflow iOS does not have operation MUL for int32 types. Is there a way I can change the data type of the input to MUL in my protobuf file or in keras saved model?

Answer (score 4):

In the creation of the model:

- Use `K.cast(tensor, K.floatx())`
- Or `tf.cast(tensor, tf.float32)`

If the model is already created, replicate it, adding the operation at the right place (when in Keras, use a `Lambda` layer for that: `Lambda(lambda x: K.cast(x,K.floatx()))`), and transfer its weights (`newModel.set_weights(oldModel.get_weights())`).

Comment: actually this problem is intenernal in conv2DTranspose , Output of that is float and so is the input, for some reason, a Mul operation is using int32